# Updating multiple fields in SQL using WHERE,WHEN,THEN

Tags: sql

I need to update multiple fields with certain conditions.  I know my syntax is incorrect but I can't figure out what's wrong, this should be easy but it's just not clicking.  Please help.

```
UPDATE WO_TASK_LABOR
SET BILLING_RATE    
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 577 THEN 26.51
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 605 THEN 18.71
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 637 THEN 16.84
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 741 THEN 16.50
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 792 THEN 26.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 808 THEN 14.99
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 812 THEN 24.51
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 813 THEN 26.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 884 THEN 28.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 768 THEN 21.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 892 THEN 21.50
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 910 THEN 20.50
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 920 THEN 22.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 962 THEN 15.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 970 THEN 23.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 971 THEN 56.36
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 977 THEN 16.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 979 THEN 24.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 982 THEN 20.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 985 THEN 18.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 828 THEN 26.50
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 834 THEN 23.00    
END
```

Comment: You could also add `where sysur_auto_key in (your list)` so you're not traversing EVERY record of wo_task_labor. but instead just those with keys you need to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `CASE`:

```
UPDATE WO_TASK_LABOR
    SET BILLING_RATE = 
    CASE
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 577 THEN 26.51
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 605 THEN 18.71
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 637 THEN 16.84
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 741 THEN 16.50
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 792 THEN 26.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 808 THEN 14.99
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 812 THEN 24.51
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 813 THEN 26.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 884 THEN 28.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 768 THEN 21.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 892 THEN 21.50
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 910 THEN 20.50
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 920 THEN 22.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 962 THEN 15.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 970 THEN 23.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 971 THEN 56.36
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 977 THEN 16.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 979 THEN 24.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 982 THEN 20.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 985 THEN 18.00
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 828 THEN 26.50
    WHEN SYSUR_AUTO_KEY = 834 THEN 23.00
    ELSE 0
    END
WHERE ENTRY_DATE >= '01-JUN-17'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it, but I need to also add a where condition i.e <WHERE ENTRY_DATE >= '01-JUN-17'> for all the those particular records, I've tried a few different iterations and I just can't get the syntax.  Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: You could use `WHERE` clause simply. I've edit my answer, please check it.

Comment: @BrandonPacheco: Kindly accept Ali's answer if it helps you :-)

Comment: I keep getting an error "SQL Error: ORA-01407: cannot update ("TRAIN"."WO_TASK_LABOR"."BILLING_RATE") to NULL
01407. 00000 -  "cannot update (%s) to NULL" I verified that the Billing_Rate field is NOT Nullable and the default value is 0 also the data_type is NUMBER(19,4) so it should be able to update to the above values, correct?

Comment: Use `ELSE` statement to to set default value. I updated my answer :(